# Balanced Panel -n and T are mixed up

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I have a fix effects model like this:

```
Indeksy <- updata.frame(PiS, index = c("Rok","Powiat")))

fixed_effects_model_05_07 <- plm(Logarytm_Wynik_Wyborczy_05_07 ~ Logarytm_bezrobotni_05_07 + Logarytm_srednie_wynagrodzenie_05_07, data = Indeksy, effect = "twoways", model = "within" )
```

and I have a result:
Balanced Panel: n = 2, T = 378, N = 756

I have a problem because it should be T = 2 and n = 378, any ideas how should I change it? I tried to change the order of `index = c("Rok","Powiat")))` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `updata.frame()` function, neither in base R nor in package `plm`.

Likely you meant `pdata.frame()` to create the specific, panel-aware data frame with two index dimension for `plm`. See the package`s first Vignettte for examples.